# Тире после "по-моему"

Tags: пунктуация

Я раньше не понимал, что можно обидеть кого-то (,) тыкая пальцем на его ошибки, по-моему (-) это услуга.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Я раньше не понимал, что можно обидеть кого-то, тыкая пальцем на его ошибки; по-моему, это услуга.***

ПО-МОЕМУ - вводное слово, ставьте запятую.

Перед ЭТО тире ставится далеко не всегда. Здесь ЭТО - подлежащее.

Точка с запятой завершает СПП - первую часть этого сложного предложения с разными видами связи, а также помогает отнести вводное слово ко второй части.

Comment: Спасибо, поставил везде запятые

Comment: Полностью согласен с @EkaterinaKashtanova4.